# Passing async data to child component leads to unpredictable rendering

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem passing data via an array and index into a child component.

```
        <div *ngIf="!template.isLoading">
        <div *ngIf="chartData[i]; else noChartDataToShow">
          <app-sankey [data]="chartData[i]"></app-sankey>
        </div>
        <ng-template id="no-chart-data" #noChartDataToShow>
          <div >No chart data available for template.</div>
        </ng-template>
        </div>
```

I have a list of elements that I iterate with ngFor. I additionally have an index. The code works as expected so far. (Not in the code snippet because irrelevant).

**The goal is to generate a chart for the clicked element on demand.**

For this purpose, I created the component "app-sankey", which will render it.

When I click on the element, it expands, a loading indicator is shown, and I make a request to get data. But subsequently, I process this data and make it suitable for the chart with:

> sankeyDiagramLogicService.buildData(data)

Only after this processing, the data should go to the child component.

Here is the ts part:

```
    if (template.isExpanded) {
  template.isLoading = true;

  this.templateService.getTemplate(currentGroup, template.name)
    .pipe(
      tap((result: TemplateDefinitionSchema)  => {

        let data: any;
        let chartData: any;
        
          data = result.properties.files?.['template.json'].definition;
          chartData = this.sankeyDiagramLogicService.buildData(data);

          this.chartData.splice(this.currentIndex, 1, chartData);

      }),
      takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
    )
    .subscribe({
      complete: () => template.isLoading = false
    });
```

My problem now is the following:

Sometimes the chart is rendered successfully in the child element, and sometimes not.

If it is not rendered, the code jumps into the else block with it:

> No chart data available for template

I therefore suspect that my asynchronous data is sometimes not yet ready for the chart in this case.

```
    <app-sankey [data]="chartData[i]"></app-sankey>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? How can I make sure that chartData[i] is ready before it is called in the component?

Comment: Can you `await` your `buildData()` call?

Comment: Side effects like that in a `tap` is a major code smell.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler That's a good point. The rxjs doc says to use tap for side effects. But breaking the stream for side effects is in itself a code smell. How would you handle this?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Converting buildData() to an async promise unfortunately did not help.

Comment: @1zz0 I'd do everything in the `subscribe`

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I tried it with subscribe() and unfortunately with the same result. Still, thanks for your input.

Comment: A simple async pipe in the ngIf?

Comment: @derstauner thanks also for your comment. Unfortunately, I already tried that with a behaviourSubject<any[]>() and async piped it. Same result. This problem just doesn't make sense. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was not an async issue at all.

My array was just the wrong data structure to use here because the indexes were wrong, when expanding the elements.

```
this.chartData.splice(this.currentIndex, 1, chartData);
```

I'm using Map with an index and object for the chartData instead, and it works just fine.

```
chartData: Map<number, {}> = new Map<number, {}>();
```

And then instead of Array.splice()

```
this.chartData.set(this.currentIndex, chartData);
```